Cessna 172 - electrical system - checklist confusion
I have been studying about Cessna 172 electrical systems and some checklists.
In the checklist, it says - AVIONIC BUS 01 and 02- TURNED OFF - BEFORE ENGINE START.
And the reason could be that in order to avoid transient voltages entering the sensitive avionics.
I found the schematic of electrical system here

In the schematic, it shows Alternator circuit is directly connected to ESS BUS via ELEC01 and ELEC02 without any control switch. And the ESS BUS in turn directly connects to avionics(PFD).If the goal is to protect avionics, then having a connection between alternator and ESS BUS wouldn’t be a problem?

Good question! The POH says "Placing the switch in the ARM position during the engine start cycle allows the standby battery to help regulate and filter essential bus voltage during the start cycle," but it's not clear to me why this would apply to the ESS BUS but not the main buses. Perhaps the diodes connecting the ESS BUS to the main buses are designed to absorb transients?

As per my understanding, diodes are devices that allow electricity to flow in one direction(only), like a valve and they do not really ‘absorb’ any transients.

It is connected via Alternator Relay, not directly connected.

In my opinion this disconnection of the "sensitive avionics" when starting/stopping the alternator is no more relevant. It seems to be the persistence of a precaution, once useful, "just in case" some equipment were not properly designed.
As you observed, the PFD and other equipment on the ESS bus are fed by the alternator even when switching it On/Off, hence are subject to transients like equipments connected to AVN 1/2 would be if the buses where not disconnected. So these ESS bus equipments are not considered as "sensitive avionics" anyway, and this could be extended to the ones on AVN 1/2 as well, in modern times.
My best guess is not powering the AVN 1/2 when starting the engine is a mean to give the starter all the available power in case the battery is not fully charged.
Voltage transients are always present
The alternator generates AC which is rectified and filtered or regulated to produce acceptable DC. This DC source then feeds various loads, which have some reactance (capacitance or inductance) as no actual load is purely resistive. Two kinds of transients are observed:

When the alternator and starter coils are switched on or off, a higher voltage appears at their terminals, due to the back-emf created by the self-inductance. This back-emf was once used in the automotive distributor ("Delco") to generate the high-voltage required by the spark plugs from a low DC voltage.

When a reactive load is connected or disconnected to/from a DC source, transient states are observed, where the voltage is not the one of the DC source.


In both cases positive or negative high-voltages can be created. Avionics equipment of the past were sensitive to these transients, but that's not the case of modern avionics. Modern avionics uses modern ICs and is protected against such known transients.
DC transients are AC
The time DC stabilizes, the voltage varies, between a low and a high value, this may occur once or several times. During this period the current is actually AC. In DC the parasitic reactance of each load (capacitance and/or inductance) plays no role, however this is not the case in AC. E.g. a capacitor, which is made of two unconnected plates separated by a dielectric, is indeed an open circuit in DC, but starts conducting in AC, the time it is fully charged.
DC equipment subject to AC transients must be designed to work in AC for a small period of time. Modern equipment deals with that by filtering its power source again, and by protecting its signal inputs.
Modern avionics is protected against transients
In modern equipment the input voltage is filtered again, there are clipping diodes (e.g. reverse Zener diodes) to limit the peaks. This comes at the price of harmonics creation which must be dealt with too. Thus the IC has calibrated + and - voltage references. Then each input is prevented to move outside the reference range using direct diodes.
You can read more in this article about the protection of a modern microcontroller. From this article, the difference between an unprotected input (top) and a protected input (bottom):


The protection is both internal to the IC (diodes) and external (resistor and capacitor).
Thus with old equipment it made sense to start the alternator with the avionics disconnected, the time for the transients to disappear. For modern avionics it is likely unnecessary, but the precaution is still there.

Completing some comments.

The diodes linking buses are to isolate them, e.g. ESS is isolated from ELEC 1/2, to prevent ESS fed by the standby battery to also feed ELEC 1/2, while at the same time ELEC 1/2 can feed ESS.

The diode in parallel with the test push-button allows to charge the standby battery with current from ELEC 1/2, but prevent the standby battery to feed them.


These diodes are not aimed for transient filtering.

Just to know, how these transients from alternator were handled in the old times?

@Theja: The usual method has been to use a big capacitor on the alternator and delay the supply of avionics until DC is stabilized. Current avionics uses CMOS (high impedance) instead of TTL (low impedance) ICs. High impedance means susceptibility to electrostatic discharges (a given voltage creates a higher current in a higher impedance), so CMOS ICs are better protected (fast clamp diodes). This protection in turn makes them accepting some supply transients.

As someone who spent 25 years in avionics design, I'll agree that modern avionics include input protection. But I've seen that, especially with general aviation, aircraft power is garbage. Newer aircraft designs are better, but most of the fleet does a really bad job. In tests, we measured transients 2 to 3 times the industry standards. And I've seen failed units where the entire protection circuit was smoked. Turning off the avionics master switch is cheap insurance.

@Gerry: I fully trust your experience and won't argue, that's a good addition. However I note in the present case, the same kind of avionics is connected to ESS and AVN buses, e.g. PFD, ADC/AHRS and NAV 1 are both connected to ESS and AVN 1. So if they are "sensitive", they are not protected when connected to ESS. Same for radios with AVN 2, only XPNDR is only connected to an AVN bus, and is really protected. This is a mystery.

Welcome to the community.
You are correct in thinking that we are protecting sensitive avionics during an engine start.
Both the main battery, external power and alternator provide electrical power to the ELEC BUS 1 and ELEC BUS 2.  The alternator switch should not be on, though during an engine start.
These two buses in turn provide electrical power to the ESS BUS and the respective AVN BUS.
As you mentioned, the avionics buses are depowered by turning off the AVIONICS BUS 1 and AVIONICS BUS 2 switch during an engine start.
The ESS BUS is powered by both the main battery and external power as well as the STANDBY BATTERY.  On the bottom of the standby battery box on the right side, it says MAIN BUS VOLTAGE SENSE and I will make the assumption the standby battery will kick in to power the ESS BUS if main battery voltage drops too low during an engine start.  In this way, the ESS BUS is protected from transient voltage fluctuations that cause damage to the avionics.  There isn't a possibility of an overvoltage with the alternator offline.

What would happen if i turn on alternator and it produce over voltage ?

How would an over voltage effect the ESS voltage ?

If an overvoltage occurs, you can begin to cause electrical issues up to frying the electrical components of the system.  You will see that in increase in the voltage on the PFD or MFD screen.  Follow the POH checklist procedure if that occurs.

The essential bus is connected directly to the standby battery when the Standby Battery Switch is in the ARM position, as it should be for engine start:

Placing the switch in the ARM position during the engine start cycle allows the standby battery to help regulate and filter essential bus voltage during the start cycle.

A battery is a device meant to hold something at a constant voltage. Thus, as the quote implies, having one in direct contact with the bus helps filter any transients from the bus.
During startup, the voltages on the main buses are lower due to the very large currents being provided by the battery, while the voltage on the ESS BUS (provided by the standby battery) will not be dropped. Those diodes only allow current to flow when the voltage on the left side is greater than the right side. So the diodes connecting ELEC BUS 1&2 to the ESS BUS should be inactive. Particularly large positive transients may still cause some current flow through the diodes, but the transients should be clipped compared to ELEC BUS 1&2 where there is no such protection.
In short, the ESS BUS is essentially disconnected from ELEC BUS 1&2 during startup, as long as the standby battery voltage is greater than or equal to the battery voltage while the starter is cranking.

The diode itself would not clip any transients I guess. Could there be any additional circuit in the system that take care of this ?
( not shown in the attached in the figure)

@Theja The diode will clip transients. Suppose the ELEC BUS 1&2 are at about 20 volts and the ESS BUS is at 24 volts (just example numbers). A 4 volt transient on the ELEC BUSes is just not enough to get current to flow through the diode so the circuit on the right won't see it at all.

What about the positive transients?
The diode will conduct when ELEC BUS VOL > ESS BUS VOL?

@Theja A positive transient of, say, 5 volts will get through the diode to some degree, but it will still be clipped- the right hand side will only see a pulse of 1 volt. The diode conducts when ELEC BUS > ESS BUS, but by the very nature of operating the starter this should not normally be the case.

Clip is probably the wrong word to use. The diode won't clip transients, but attenuate them, taking a couple of volts (depending on the diode) off the transient, passing any remaining voltage increase on.

As shown on the diagram, the [ALT Output] is never "directly connected" to [ELEC BUS 1].
It is provisionally connected through [ALTERNATOR RELAY].  When the Alternator Relay is open, [ELEC BUS 1] is only connected to the battery.
[ALT MASTER] controls both ACU [Power In] and [ALTERNATOR RELAY]. [Power In] provides the field current for the Alternator.
You do not wish to provide field current to the alternator while starting, for two reasons:
(1) That would be stupid. You're going to use electricity to turn the starter motor, to turn the alternator, to provide electricity.  Doing that just throws away power: you get less than you put in.
(2) The field current is unlimited* when the alternator is stalled. You can flatten your battery and burn out your alternator. You don't want to provide field current unless your alternator is running at speed.
(*Controlled by the ACU. You should consider posting any further questions about circuit diagrams, or alternator field currents, to Electrical Engineering stack exchange, rather than avionics.)
